# How to define myAnnotationProcessor programmatically in source code?

Tags: java, annotations

I'm just new to annotations.
I've created a sample annotationProcessor to handle my annotations and currently using command line script "-processor defaultproject.annotations.DefaultProcessor " to use it.

is there any way to set this processor from inside the code?

thanks a lot
Moein

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Processor interface](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/Processor.html) says this about the discovery process:

> The tool uses a *discovery process* to find annotation processors and
>   decide whether or not they should be run. By configuring the tool, the
>   set of potential processors can be controlled. For example, for a
>   [JavaCompiler](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) the list of candidate processors to run can be [set
>   directly](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.CompilationTask.html#setProcessors%28java.lang.Iterable%29) or controlled by a [search path](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/StandardLocation.html#ANNOTATION_PROCESSOR_PATH) used for a
>   [service-style lookup](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html). Other tool implementations may have
>   different configuration mechanisms, such as command line options; for
>   details, refer to the particular tool's documentation.

Your best bet for defining the processor in your classpath is to provide a `META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor` file containing the text `defaultproject.annotations.DefaultProcessor`.

*(Assuming your tool chain supports this mechanism. This is ultimately compiler/tool/IDE dependent.)*

Comment: So sorry

I did try , like this :

<code>
        ArrayList<Processor> processors 
        processors.add(new MyDefaultProcessor());

        JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
        StandardJavaFileManager fileManager =   compiler.getStandardFileManager(null, null, null);
        CompilationTask compilationTask = compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, null, null, null, null);

        compilationTask.setProcessors(processors);
        compilationTask.call();
</code>

But I don't know how to replace parameters currently passed 'null'.

Thanks a lot

Comment: @user847577 - see [this developerWorks article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jcomp/index.html) by David Biesack on dynamic compilation. If you are still having trouble invoking the API, that should probably be a new question.